# including necessary packages in .pyc file

Tags: python, module

I have a small program I am trying pass around to friends.  It includes nonstandard libraries like the PIL and  mtTkinter packages, and thus usually requires them to be included in the pythonpath.

Is there a way I can generate the the .pyc file so that all required code for the program to run is included in the file, and not required to be installed on my friends computers. I want this to be able to work between different OS like windows, mac, and linux.

Comment: There's not really any easy way to do that, and you're probably misunderstanding what a .pyc file is really about, Python doesn't really have a "linker" like in C.

Comment: @wim Is there something like pyinstaller or py2exe that can compile them into non-OS specific code?

Comment: No, because Python interpreter itself has OS specific code. Just specify your dependencies correctly and distribute your package on PyPI as usual (users will install with `pip`). Platform-specific dependency specifiers are supported in `setup.py`.

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to a pyc file?  I use pyinstaller to package programs and share. The first time I used it, I couldn't believe how easy it is.

Here's a link to the portion on packaging for multiple operating systems: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#supporting-multiple-operating-systems

Comment: pyinstaller requires you to bundle your app separately on each platform.